# Getting a strange error for substringWithRange

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a strange issue with substringWithRange function.

I have an NSString with a length of 22.

When I do this:

```
NSString *result = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 21)];
```

Everything is fine. But when I try to get something from middle, like:

```
NSString *result = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11, 14)];
```

It gives an out of bounds exception.

> 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'

So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A NSRange is not "from index to index". It is "from index with length".

Why the first one works? I have no idea. I guess in reality your string is not 22 characters long but 24.

Answer (score 0):

NSRange return start position and length. Why length instead end position? Because for example in string `Night Café` code `[str rangeOfString:@"Café"]` will return length 5, because `Café` is in memory will be look like `Cafe´` (5 bytes in memory for 4 letter word).

Comment: nope, [str rangeOfString:@"Café"] returns a length of 4. That's why we use NSString instead of raw bytes. Because we don't have to care for encodings and memory representations.